# Overwrite worksheet using googlesheets in R

Tags: r, overwrite, google-sheets-api, worksheet, r-googlesheets

I have 2 questions.

1. How do you overwrite a worksheet in an existing spreadsheet using the googlesheets package in R?
2. How do you create a new worksheet in an existing spreadsheet using the googlesheets package in R?

I could not find anything in [the documentation.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/basic-usage.html#edit-cells)

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite data in a worksheet directly using `gs_edit_cells()` using the `trim = TRUE` option to erase whatever extra was in the sheet. As the documentation points out, use of this function and, therefore, any functions that rely on it (including `gs_ws_new()` if `input` is not NULL) will be *[extremely slow](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/338)*.

The only other option available is to construct a complete file with all the worksheets of interest (*e.g.* .xlsx) and use `gs_upload()`, which will overwrite your entire file.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new worksheet in an existing spreadsheet:

```
require(googlesheets)
#first get the existing spreadsheet
existing_spreadsheet <- gs_title("title")  
#Then add the new worksheet to the existing sheet 
gs_ws_new(existing_spreadsheet
       , ws_title = "worksheet title"  #make sure it doesn't exist already
       , input = your_input #data.frame or data.table
       , trim = TRUE  #optional if you want your worksheet trimed
              )
```

I haven't been able to find a direct way to overwrite a worksheet in an existing spreadsheet myself. So i've had to delete the existing worksheet and add it again as a new worksheet.

```
#first delete the existing worksheet
existing_spreadsheet <- gs_ws_delete(existing_spreadsheet, "work sheet title you want updated")
# Then add the newworksheet with new data
gs_ws_new(existing_spreadsheet
        , ws_title = "worksheet title" 
        , input = your_new_data #data.frame or data.table
        , trim = TRUE  #optional if you want your worksheet trimed
      )
```